# Что означает такой фрагмент кода: globals()[code]()

Tags: python

Изучая один код, столкнулся с выражением:

```
a, b = globals()[code]()
```

Здесь `code` - это записанный в виде текста некий код.

Что же это за такой вызов функции ?

Не мог бы кто-нибудь подсказать, xоть откуда это?

Answer (score 2):

`globals()` - вернет словарь глобальных директив, определенных в текущем модуле.

```
print(globals())
```

Вернет:

```
{
    '__name__': '__main__', 
    '__doc__': None, 
    '__package__': None,  
    '__spec__': None, 
    '__annotations__': {}, 
    '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 
    [...]
}
```

А конкретно

```
print(globals()[code])
```

Вернет указанную директиву, где `code` будет клюем в словаре, чтобы вернуть вам значение из текущего словаря.

```
print(globals()['__name__'])
```

Вернет  `__main__`.
Ну и собственно, дальше идет обычный вызов функции:

```
b = globals()['__name__']();
```

Comment: @Сергей, рядом с ответом моим, есть галочка, нажмите на нее.